# Installing scipy and scikit-learn: "pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run" "This is a Meson bug and should be reported!"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [93 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environme
nt
      Collecting setuptools<60.0
        Downloading setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
           ------------------------------------ 952.8/952.8 kB 198.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 2
     
        [56 lines of output]
        + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ben5_8e4\scipy_1131f781
80814dcc9c546f7015a07677 C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ben5_8e4\scipy_1131f78180814dcc9c546f7015a07677\.mesonpy-2xsujna7\build --native-file=C:
\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ben5_8e4\scipy_1131f78180814dcc9c546f7015a07677\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\mesonmain.py", line 194, in run
            return options.run_func(options)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\msetup.py", line 310, in run
            app.generate()
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\msetup.py", line 187, in generate
            self._generate(env)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\msetup.py", line 209, in _generate
            intr = interpreter.Interpreter(b, user_defined_options=user_defined_options)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreter\interpreter.py", line 328, in __init_
_
            self.parse_project()
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 117, in
 parse_project
            self.evaluate_codeblock(self.ast, end=1)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 172, in
 evaluate_codeblock
            raise e
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 165, in
 evaluate_codeblock
            self.evaluate_statement(cur)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 178, in
 evaluate_statement
            return self.function_call(cur)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 460, in
 function_call
            res = func(node, func_args, kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\decorators.py", line 277, in wrap
per
            return f(*nargs, **wrapped_kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\decorators.py", line 590, in wrap
per
            return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreter\interpreter.py", line 1245, in func_p
roject
            self.add_languages(proj_langs, True, MachineChoice.HOST)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreter\interpreter.py", line 1381, in add_la
nguages
            success = self.add_languages_for(args, required, for_machine)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\interpreter\interpreter.py", line 1421, in add_la
nguages_for
            comp = compilers.detect_compiler_for(self.environment, lang, for_machine)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\compilers\detect.py", line 115, in detect_compile
r_for
            comp = compiler_from_language(env, lang, for_machine)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\compilers\detect.py", line 112, in compiler_from_
language
            return lang_map[lang](env, for_machine) if lang in lang_map else None
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\compilers\detect.py", line 577, in detect_c_compi
ler
            return _detect_c_or_cpp_compiler(env, 'c', for_machine)
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\compilers\detect.py", line 293, in _detect_c_or_c
pp_compiler
            found_cl = sanitize(shutil.which('cl'))
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_dv9qhi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonbuild\compilers\detect.py", line 287, in sanitize
            return os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(p))
          File "C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 527, in abspath
            return normpath(_getfullpathname(path))
        TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.0.1
        Source dir: C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ben5_8e4\scipy_1131f78180814dcc9c546f7015a07677
        Build dir: C:\Users\alibaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ben5_8e4\scipy_1131f78180814dcc9c546f7015a07677\.mesonpy-2xsujna7\build
        Build type: native build
        Project name: SciPy
        Project version: 1.10.1
     
        ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unhandled python exception
     
            This is a Meson bug and should be reported!
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
     
      Encountered error while generating package metadata.
     
      See above for output.
     
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
python -m pip install scipy
```

my python version is 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtual environment using python or anaconda, and run the pip install commands again. That works because it is possible that your current environment dependencies are different and pip is using them
.